# How to stream a linked file in Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, amazon, file-manager

I have a set of Zip files I want to host on my website.  However I don't want anyone to be able to simply grab them whenever they want.

I have seen other sites that use file streaming to handle this with like S3 as the file hosting.

My plan would be to setup a CPT called "resource" and have a file path field that would include the link to the S3 hosted zip file.

Then when the user clicks a button, I would stream the file to the user.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

Your answer may be with Youtube you can put videos on there and set them so that the only people that can find them must have the full url. Then you can control who gets the URL path. I have seen pay sites actually do this. Just a suggestion.

Comment: The question is about streaming zip files, what do youtube videos have to do with it?

Comment: Youtube is an alternative to hosting them yourself like most of the world does nowadays. No need to zip them or host them. Maybe you have heard of youtube? I hear it is pretty popular

Comment: This of course is assuming he is talking about streaming video.

Comment: The question clearly talks about `zip` file. Not videos.

Comment: I am not referring to videos.  I am delivering source code for my products to customers so that they can build their products.